# Styling imported from svelte style tag stays when moving back to old page

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Two of my svelte kit pages have similar styling, so i extracted it to a scss file, and imported the file using @use. Like so:

```html
<style lang="scss">
@use "../some-styles.scss";
</style>
```

It works fine and all, but when I go from one of my pages that doesn't use that styling to a page that does use the styling, the original page takes on that styling. If I go back, the page still has that styling, and I need to refresh in order to remove it.

For example if on page 1 I don't have any styling on `code` elements but on page 2 I import a file with:

```css
code {
   background-color: green;
}
```

If i go from page 1 to page 2, back to page 1, the `<code>` will have a green background.

How do i fix this?

I've tried using `import "../some-styles.scss"` on the scrip tag, but there's some issues with that. Such as `:global()` not working, and some styles not being applied.

I thought about creating a base component for both of them, but they have different structures so I don't know how well that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not using `:global` without scoping it first, otherwise those rules really should apply globally.

If you have multiple pages that should use the style, you could define a class to be used as indicator on some root container and only use `:global` within that scope if required.

E.g.

```scss
.page-style {
  :global(input) {
     // ...
  }
}
```